# Automatically generated predicate row templates for to-many key?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicateeditor

In my Core Data managed object model, I have an entity Foo with a to-many relationship (with a to-many inverse) to entity Baz named baz. Baz has a string property named "tag". When I use `[NSPredicateRowEditorTemplate templatesWithAttributeKeyPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"baz.tag"] inEntityDescription:FooDescription]` to create the row editors for an NSPredicateEditor, the result contains (as expected) a row template like

[Popup: baz.tag] [Popup: Contains|is|is not|...] [TextField]

When I select "Contains" from the popup, a query with the predicate works as expected. If I choose any of the other popups (e.g. "is"), I get the following error: "to-many key not allowed here". Can I use `[NSPredicateRowEditorTemplate templatesWithAttributeKeyPaths:inEntityDescription:]` or do I have to build the row editor manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the automatically generated template (using `[NSPredicateRowEditorTemplate templatesWithAttributeKeyPaths:inEntityDescription:]`) cannot produce the correct operators. The solution is to create the template manually using `[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate initWithLeftExpressions:rightExpressionAttributeType:modifier:operators:options:]`. For the given example:

```
id template = [[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate initWithLeftExpressions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"baz.tag"]] rightExpressionAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType modifier:NSAnyPredicateModifier operators:keywordOperators options:0];
```